# ¿Cómo "fusionar" dos instancias de una misma clase?

Tags: java, groovy

El código es groovy pero la respuesta puede ser en Java, no hay problema.
Tengo una clase Persona con los siguientes atributos:

```
class Persona(){
String nombre
String apellido
}
```

y tengo un método que me devuelve dos objetos de tipo persona, uno con unos atributos y otro con el resto. En mi ejemplo sería como si tuviera:

```
persona1 = "nombre : Juan"
persona2 = "apellido : Gónzalez"
```

Y al "fusionarlo" lo que quiero es que a persona1 se le añadan los atributos **que no tenga** pero que si tenga persona2. El output en este ejemplo sería:

```
persona1.merge(persona2)
persona1= "nombre : Juan, apellido : Gónzalez"
```

¿Existe algún método de la api de java o groovy que me permita hacer este "merge" sin escribir cada atributo a mano (iterando sobre todos los atributos para no tener que cambiar el código si se añaden o quitan atributos)?

En caso de que no exista, ¿Se puede hacer un bucle para iterar sobre los distintos atributos de una clase para chequear uno a uno el valor de ese atributo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Entiendo que puedes hacerlo mediante una condición if-else mismamente.

```
if (persona1.apellido == null) {
  if (persona2.apellido != null) {
   persona1.apellido = persona2.apellido;
  }
}
```

Lo mismo para el resto de atributos.

**EDIT:** Para que no tengas que hacerlo por cada atributo, o para cuando introduzcas nuevos, te dejo este enlace en el que puedes ver como recorrer todos los atributos de una clase: [Loop Class Attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17095628/loop-over-all-fields-in-a-java-class)

```
Field[] atributos= Persona.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
for(Field f : atributos){
  //Operaciones que necesites por cada atributo de la clase
}
```

Comment: hombre, puse un ejemplo muy sencillo para que se entendiera pero la respuesta que busco es un método que me permita hacer eso pero sin poner cada atributo uno a uno (en mi caso tengo muchos más y se pueden añadir más en cualquier momento), no quiero tener que cambiar el código cuando se añadan más clases. Voy a editar la pregunta para ser algo más claro en ese aspecto.

Comment: Edito con el Loop a los atributos de una clase @Blazerg

Comment: Las clases de `java.lang.reflect` son como una pistola... si no sabes muy bien qué estás haciendo y porqué lo estás haciendo, es muy probable que te acabes pegando un tiro. Recomiendo encarecidamente el primer enfoque (posiblemente en un método de la misma clase); casi con seguridad cualquier "ahorro" que consigas usando el segundo enfoque lo acabarás pagando varias veces cuando te encuentres con casos especiales, cambios por mantenimiento, etc.

Comment: @SJuan76 Me podrías poner algún ejemplo de esos casos especiales que podrían fallar con el bucle que ha compartido Flowen???

Comment: @Flowen, el método que has puesto devuelve mucha info pero no devuelve los atributos de la clase. He pintado el contenido de esa lista y me devuelve "serialVersionUID, serialPersistentFields, reflectionFactory..."

Comment: @Blazerg por ejemplo, con reflection puedes obtener o los atributos actuales públicos de la clase o los atributos privados. No puedes obtener directamente los atributos que posee la clase debido a herencia. Tienes que hacer un recorrido manual y evaluar dichos campos también. Así mismo, puede que hagas una evaluación equivocada y se comience a corromper la data de `persona1` y `persona2`. Recomiendo investigar mucho al respecto y hacer muchas pruebas. O, mejor usar la opción de comparar los atributos manualmente.

Answer (score 1):

lo puedes hacer facilmente con org.apache.commons.beanutils 
 BeanUtils.copyProperties(Object dest, Object orig);

puedes tambien excluir atributos nulos o que no cumplan cierta condición.
Ref. http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-copy-properties-from-one-bean-to-another.html